# Selecting trailing empty nodes using xpath

Tags: xslt, xpath

How do I select trailing empty nodes? Empty, as in no text, that is.
In this example I want to ignore the first empty node, as it is not trailing, The last three nodes (under `<bar>`) have no text so I want to select them.

```
<foo>
    <bar>
        <node>blah blah</node>
        <node></node>                     <-- Not this
        <node>blah blah</node>
        <node>blah blah</node>
        <node></node>                     <-- But this
        <node><node></node></node>        <-- and this
    </bar>
</foo>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `/foo/bar/node[not(normalize-space()) and not(following-sibling::node[normalize-space()])]` you select the two `node` child elements that don't have any following sibling with text content. The second of those `node` elements contains a further `node` child, I am not sure whether you want to select that as well as part of the result.